# send kafka retryable message to one topic via spring retry

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-retry

I use spring retry to implement a retry system for kafka consumer. My consumer code is

```
package com.kafka.errorhandling.demo.listener;

import org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.DltHandler;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.RetryableTopic;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.KafkaHeaders;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.DeserializationException;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Header;
import org.springframework.retry.annotation.Backoff;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class MyKafkaListener {

    @RetryableTopic(
            attempts = "5",
            autoCreateTopics = "false",
            backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000, multiplier = 2.0),
            exclude = {SerializationException.class, DeserializationException.class}

    )
    @KafkaListener(id = "${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}", topics = "${topic}")
    public void handleMessage(String message, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic) {
        log.info("Received message: {} from topic: {}", message, topic);
        throw new RuntimeException("Test exception");
    }

    @DltHandler
    public void handleDlt(String message, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic) {
        log.info("Message: {} handled by dlq topic: {}", message, topic);
    }
}
```

I understood that spring will create a retry topic for every attempt, can i create just one destination topic for all retry messages?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not with an exponential back off.

With a fixed back off delay (no multiplier), you can set `fixedDelayTopicStrategy = FixedDelayStrategy.SINGLE_TOPIC` and only one retry topic is used.

**EDIT**

Here's an example with a custom naming strategy...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Gitter1Application extends RetryTopicConfigurationSupport {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Gitter1Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected RetryTopicComponentFactory createComponentFactory() {
        return new RetryTopicComponentFactory() {

            @Override
            public RetryTopicNamesProviderFactory retryTopicNamesProviderFactory() {
                return new MyNamesProvider();
            }

        };
    }

    @Bean
    TaskScheduler sched() {
        return new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> {
            template.send("gitter1", "foo");
        };
    }

}

@Component
class Listener {

    @KafkaListener(id = "gitter1", topics = "gitter1")
    @RetryableTopic(attempts = "3", fixedDelayTopicStrategy = FixedDelayStrategy.SINGLE_TOPIC)
    void listen(String in, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic) {
        System.out.println(in + " from " + topic);
        throw new RuntimeException("test");
    }

    @DltHandler
    void dlt(String in) {
        System.out.println(in + " from DLT");
    }
}

class MyNamesProvider implements RetryTopicNamesProviderFactory {

    @Override
    public RetryTopicNamesProvider createRetryTopicNamesProvider(Properties properties) {
        return new SuffixingRetryTopicNamesProvider(properties) {

            @Override
            public String getTopicName(String topic) {
                if (properties.isMainEndpoint()) {
                    return topic;
                }
                else if (properties.isDltTopic()) {
                    return "myDLT";
                }
                return "myCustomSingleRetryTopic";
            }

        };
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you @Gary , and how can i customize the topic name?

Comment: See the documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#topic-naming and here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#custom-naming-strategies I also added a complete example that I provided for someone on Gitter recently.