# Configuring a single, custom retry-topic for FIXED Delay non-blocking retries in Spring Kafka

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I want to configure a custom Retry topic that will provide the fixed delay functionality for retries.
I followed the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75723808/send-kafka-retryable-message-to-one-topic-via-spring-retry) and setup up all the configurations (spring-kafka.version 2.9.13).

My code:

```
@RetryableTopic(autoCreateTopics = "false", kafkaTemplate = "kafkaEventMessageTemplate", attempts = "3", fixedDelayTopicStrategy = FixedDelayStrategy.SINGLE_TOPIC, backoff = @Backoff(delayExpression = "10000", multiplierExpression = "0"), include = {CustomRetryableException.class})

@KafkaListener(topics = "${test-topic-main}", groupId ="${config.consumer.group-id}", containerFactory = "kafkaConcurrentListenerContainerFactory")*  
public void receiveMessage(MyPOJO<Object1, Object2> kafkaMessage, Acknowledgment ack) throws IOException {
            log.info("testing retry for kafka", coreKafkaMessage);
    try{
obj1.processMessage(kafkaMessage);
}        
catch(CustomRetryableException cgre) {
            throw cgre;
        }
}



public class MyNamesProvider implements RetryTopicNamesProviderFactory {

     @Override
        public RetryTopicNamesProvider createRetryTopicNamesProvider(DestinationTopic.Properties properties) {
            return new SuffixingRetryTopicNamesProvider(properties) {

                @Override
                public String getTopicName(String topic) {
                    if (properties.isMainEndpoint()) {
                        return topic;
                    }
                    else if (properties.isDltTopic()) {
                        return "dummy";
                    }
                    return "mynew.retryable.topic";
                }

            };
        }

}
```

I created a topic in my Kafka Confluent console and used that name in the RetryTopicNamesProviderFactory implementation.

Then I created a CustomRetryableException class and included that in @Retryable configuration. Now, I can see that the Spring-Kafka retries the message when I throw the CustomRetryableException from obj1.processMessage(kafkaMessage). However, the retried message just sits in the custom retryable topic which I can see in the Kafka Console and nothing happens after that.

Do I need to write any new consumer/Listener service for a custom retry topic to work ? Please guide me If I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a new Kafka listener that specifically listens to your custom retry topic `mynew.retryable.topic`. This listener will consume messages from the retry topic and process them further.

Make sure that the group id for the retry topic listener is different from the main topic listener's group id to avoid conflicts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did setup a new listener for that topic. and I am able to fetch the RetryTopicHeaders.DEFAULT_HEADER_ATTEMPTS. However if there is any exception during the processing then it does not follow the retry timeout configurations that I have configured in my main listener @Retryable. In short, I do not see any further retry attempts in case of processing failure. How can I ensure that the custom retry topic is called "x" number of times after a fixed delay.

Comment: Your retry topic listener needs its own retry configuration. This is because the retry behavior for the original listener (@RetryableTopic) does not automatically apply to the listener for the retry topic. You'll need to implement a retry mechanism for this listener as well.

Comment: Thanks I tried to add @RetryableTopic on this but now I get a duplicate key error, as the listener topic and the retryable topic are the same.  I only have one retry topic available to me so not able to implement retry mechanism on the listener for the retry topic.  error-->Duplicate key org.springframework.kafka.retrytopic.DefaultDestinationTopicResolver$DestinationTopicHolder

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve. Typically, only the main consumer has a retry mechanism. The retry topic consumer does not retry but either process successfully or moves the message to a DLT. There are different best practices on how to handle it, but it's not related to your original topic anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that fixedDelayTopicStrategy was not working as expected and so I tried implementing a custom listener for the retry topic to process the message with delay.

The issue got resolved after removing the group id from my main topic listener and also providing a real topic name in the RetryTopicNamesProvider for the DLT topic. I was giving a dummy name in the properties.isDltTopic() logic as I do not want to send the message automatically to DLT after retries are exhausted.

The fixedDelayTopicStrategy was not working because of the group id configured on the main listener, it was conflicting with the delayed retry logic.